# Axis for log graph Rstudio

Tags: r, logging, rstudio

My current [df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqzqE.png) is really long but I will add a short picture here. I get a graph like this [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXhYl.png). The data goes from 0-27000 on the x axis so there should not be a graph like this. A long straight line would be the expected results. On top of that I am trying yo make the x and y axis a log.

```
 a %>% 
      ggplot(aes(Discharge, Gageheight)) +
      geom_point()
```

Getting better at adding info so advice on posts would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Try `!(GageList2$GAGE %in% resulterrors$GAGE)` rather than doing a `!=` test.

Comment: Sorry forgot to respond. This worked perfectly thank you!